# How can i auto fill those bootstrap_form fields when i enter certain id then those id related data is auto filled in django

Tags: python, django

this is my model and when i enter some data it goes to database and i want to retrive that data in a form field automatically i am using bootstrap_form when i enter there id like when i enter id then name:something,address:something like this data is autofilled in form fields.Please help i am new to django.

```
    # Create your models here.
    user_sex = (('Male','male'),('Female','female'))
    
This is my Student Registration model
    class StudentRegistration(models.Model):
        Id = models.ForeignKey(unique=True)
        StudentName = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        Std_Address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        std_phone = models.CharField(null = False , blank = False, unique = True,max_length=150)
        Email = models.EmailField()
        faculty = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        parents_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        parents_phone = models.CharField(null = False , blank = False, unique = True,max_length=150)
        join_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        Registration_No = models.IntegerField(unique = True)
        sex = models.CharField(default='Male',choices=user_sex,max_length=150)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.StudentName,self.Registration_No
    
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('registration:stdlist')
        
        def save(self,*args,**Kwargs):
            return super().save(*args,**Kwargs)
    
    This is my Staff registration Detail


    class StaffRegistration(models.Model):
        Id = models.ForeignKey(unique=True)
        Name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        Address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        Email = models.EmailField()
        phone = models.CharField(null = False,blank = False,unique = True,max_length=150)
        Join_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        sex = models.CharField(default='Male',choices=user_sex,max_length=150)
    
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.Name,self.Address
        
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("registration:stafflist")
        
        def save(self,*args,**Kwargs):
            self.slug = slugify(self.Name)
            return super().save(*args,**Kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

incase of update the data when u enter id of object u want to update and want it to come with current instance or property they have u need to add jinja on the html_template form in attribute value eg value={{student.name}}

Comment: i wanna add in a functionality that is when i give an employee his/her salary and when i enter the id the fields are filled automatically like name address related to that id

Comment: and i am using {% bootstrap_form form %}

Comment: try to learn jquery function known as Keyup()

Comment: ok but can i get your any contact of social media where i can talk with you more? if u dont mind